About the scansion of Iliad I 11
Disclaimer: cross-post of this Quora question.
Iliad book 1 l. 11 reads:

Οὕνεκα τὸν Χρύσην ἠτίμησεν ἀρητῆρα

The syllable quantities seem to be –uu– – – – – – uu– –u, so –uu|– –|– – (Οὕνεκα | τὸν Χρύ|σην ἠ-) are the first three feet, but how would one split – – uu– –u (-τίμησεν ἀρητῆρα) into feet that would fit the hexameter meter?

There doesn't seem to be an etymological reason to suppose a lost
digamma, nor a reason to make the first eta of ἀρητῆρα short and thus
see – – – – uu–u (-τίμη|σεν *ϝαρε|τῆρα).
There is no way to make the -mē- short and even then the a- of
ἀρητῆρα is not long so –uu– - –u (-*τίμεσεν | ἀρη|τῆρα) is also a
no-go

But then how? Are there other examples of line like this? It almost looks like the fifth foot is supposed to be an anapest, as if a dactyl had been flipped by anaclasis… is this a thing that can happen?

I don't know what text you're using but all printed and online editions I checked say ἠτίμασεν. OCT lists your ἠτίμησεν as a second variant (the third variant is ἠτίμησ')

@ba I think I took the tezt from Greek Wikisource. Still, we'd have to assume the α- in αρητηρα is long... Metri causa? And the first variant would require the -α- to be short. Unless I'm missing something, that is.

It's known to be a funky line, but it's scanned like so:

οὕνεκα | τὸν Χρύ|σην ἠ|τίμασεν | ἀρη|τῆρα

The initial alpha in ἀρητῆρα can indeed be long, as LSJ show. Beekes' explains the reasoning under the entry for ἀρά:

Arcadian shows a pre-form *ἀρϝά, which neatly explains the difference in quantity of ἀ- in Ionic and Attic. The final -α in Attic ἀρά poses problems, however, since we expect -η after *ϝ Perhaps it is from (-)ἀράομαι or from the frequent plural ἀραί (cf. Schwyzer: 1882).

Metrically, while it's not as common, it's still legitimate to have a spondee in the penult. Per Arthur Ludwich, about there's a spondee in about 6% of the penult foot (rounding up).

So I was confused by a wrong text (ητιμησεν in place of ητιμασεν), a short α where I'd expect a long one because IIRC the thematic vowel usually lengthens in aorists, and a long α in αρητηρα which I didn't know was possible. Funky line indeed :)

Specifically, the long alpha in ἀρητῆρα is because of an original digamma, but it's a digamma after the ρ; it's the Ionic second compensatory lengthening. This had probably already taken place at the time, but even if it hadn't it doesn't matter for the meter.

@MickG See Cairnarvon's comment above, too.

@Cairnarvon That's something I'd like to see in an answer!

@MickG That short alpha isn't actually a stem-final vowel -- the form is from ατιμάζω rather than ατιμάω.

You mean Liddell and Scott.

@Figulus Oops, thanks. Fixed.
